# MySQL slow query when using GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, indexing, group-by, key, inner-join

I'm using 2 tables to join packages to shippings:

**packages**

```
CREATE TABLE `packages` (
  `package` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `shipping` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

ALTER TABLE `packages`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`package`,`shipping`);
COMMIT;
```

**shippings**

```
CREATE TABLE `shippings` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

ALTER TABLE `shippings`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `shippings`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;COMMIT;
```

the problem is when I try to join packages to shippings and GROUP BY e.g. for counting packages in each shipping:

```
SELECT s.id,COUNT(*) packages
FROM shippings s
INNER JOIN packages p ON s.id=p.shipping
GROUP BY s.id
```

with 5K shippings and 10K packages records the query take more than 10s to execute, maybe I'm missing some keys or indexes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to add an index for the packages.shipping. The primary key index that you have will not be used in the query as it has the package as the first level.

Alternatively you can change the order of the primary key columns in the packages-table, but that depends on what other queries use the table.

Comment: I set both packages.package and packages.shipping as primary key because they must be unique

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that

Comment: Sorry I hit enter before ending write. Do you mean to add a FK for packages.shipping? What would change if I reverse the order of PKs?

Comment: You can add a foreign key for the packages.shipping referencing shippings.id. This will automatically create an index for packages.shipping thus speeding up your query. Reversing the PK will also speed up the query as the shipping-index can be used in the query. On the downside queries using package-column directly will not benefit from the index, so the best option is to add a FK.

Comment: adding the FK for packages.shipping and shippings.id worked, now the query executes in 1s. So even the order of columns affects the queries execution speed and so placing packages.shipping as first column improves queries that concern shipping field but worsens the queries that concern package field?

Comment: When an index has multiple columns, the index can be utlilized in the order the columns are defined. An index with columns A,B will be not used when WHERE statement uses only B. It will be used when A or A+B is used (somewhat simplified example).

Comment: clear, and when A+B is used I should put the column in most used (or heavy) queries first right?

Comment: @Miky - If you have a variety of `SELECTs`, you might need multiple `INDEXes`.  Let's see a sampling of your `SELECTs` (and `UPDATEs` and `DELETEs`).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT s.id,COUNT(*) packages
FROM shippings s
INNER JOIN packages p ON s.id=p.shipping
GROUP BY s.id
```

can be simplified to

```
SELECT p.shipping AS id,
       COUNT(*) AS packages
FROM packages p
GROUP BY p.shipping
```

From there, you need some index *starting with* `shipping`.  You could either swap the order of the columns in the PK, or add `INDEX(shipping)`.

Comment: yes that's how I solved, as also slaakso answered. about the query you are right the join is not needed but I simplified it to circumscribe the problem, in the original query I need other fields of the table shippings